# how to extract zip file from assets in external Storage via ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android

> here is my code, I think doInBackground method is not running, this code makes targetfolder but it is empty , I wanna to Extract myzipfile.zip in targetfolder

get path of zip file in MainActivity

```
String zipFilename = this.getAssets().openFd("raw/"+"myzipfile.zip")";
String unzipLocation = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/targetfolder";
final Decompress d = new Decompress(zipFilename, unzipLocation);
d.execute();
```

make Decompree class for unzipping in background

```
private class Decompress extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

private String _zipFile;
private String _location;
private int per = 0;
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(_zipFile);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(zip.size());
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile);
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {

            Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName());
            if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                _dirChecker(ze.getName());
            } else {

                per++;
                publishProgress(per);

                FileOutputStream fout = new 
FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName());
                for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
                    fout.write(c);
                }
                zin.closeEntry();
                fout.close();
            }
        }
        zin.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e);
    }

    return null;
}}}
```

Comment: Since an APK is a ZIP file, why are you storing a ZIP file inside of a ZIP file? I recommend unpacking the contents of `myzipfile.zip` into your project's `assets/` directory. Then, at runtime, you can copy the assets to storage. Note that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprecated in API Level 29, and it will not be available to you in Android Q (by default) and Android R+ (for all apps).

Comment: I can see foldertarget by    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()    my qusetion is "why doInBackground is not working